How to perform a variable number of positional substitutions
Given a file:
ab abc a abc def
fgh fg hg gg ddd

I can surround each word with an apostrophe by doing (in Vim at least):
:%s/\w\+/'&'/g

But if my file is:
abc 1 ab abc a abc def
x 2 fgh fg hg gg ddd

and I only want to surround the words after the second field (the digit), I might choose to search for the pattern
^\w\+ \w\+ \w\+\( \w\+\)*

assuming there was at least one word after the digit.
Is there a sensible way to substitute all the words following the digit with a command along the lines of:
:%s/^\w\+ \w\+ \zs\w\+\( \w\+\)*\ze/<some replacement>/g

or should I be looking at a different approach? I'm interested in regex solutions only.

Please add the expected output to the question. Is it required to do this with vim? Or would it be possible to use other tools like awk?

Please add an input - expected output and possibly a place to test vim regex; dont know if the following is compatible! So far I assume you look for something like this? \K could be used instead of (*SKIP)(*FAIL)

You can use
:%s/\(^\w\+\s\+\d.*\)\@<=\<\w\+/'&'/g
:%s/\v(^\w+\s+\d.*)@<=<\w+/'&'/g

The patterns are the same, just the second one uses the "very magic mode" to avoid overescaping.
The \(^\w\+\s\+\d.*\)\@<= (or (^\w+\s+\d.*)@<= in very magic mode) is a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a word, one or more whitespaces, then a digit and then any amount of any characters immediately to the left of the current location.
The \< (or < in the very magic mode) is the left word boundary, which is necessary to match words from their start position.

Solution using awk.
The script will enclose all fields after the second one in single quotes and replace multiple spaces or tabs with a single space.
The assignment of a single quote to variable q simplifies the quoting inside the script.
awk -v q="'" '{ for(i=3; i<=NF; i++) { $i = q $i q } print }' inputfile > outputfile


Edit:  (sorry, I interpreted the question only on what was in the title, and I misinterpreted it)
You have several possibilities, running sed(1) from inside vim(1):

substitute all words into quoted strings.
then check on lines that have the second word as a number, unquote them.

The first command chan be achieved with the following command:
:%s/\w\+/'&'/g

(with plain vi you cannot use \w or \s, so you need to use something like:
:%s/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*/'&'/g

(this is the first command you had) and now:
:%g/'\(\w\w*\)'\(  *\)'\([0-9][0-9]*\)'/s//\1\2\3/

(we select a global pattern over the whole file, for a group of ' word ' blank ' digit_pattern ' and substitute it (I have used groups in the first pattern to repeat them in the substitute command (the empty // selects the same last pattern before) and change it into the three groups without the apostrophes)

Another approach is to use the filtering command of vim and pass it through a sed filter that does the two things in one shot:
:%!sed -Ee "s/[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*/'&'/g" -e "s/^'([a-zA-Z]*)'(  *)([0-9][0-9]*)/\1\2\3/"

(this works in vim(1) and vi(1), normal vi doesn't support regex extensions like \w or \s, so almost equivalent expressions have been worked out)

"You cannot" is a curious way to start your answer considering Wiktor gave an answer that works in Vim. I assume OP meant to use Vim's regexp engine with whatever extensions it contains.
